# How to assign to struct pointer from another method

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, arduino

So I am not that well versed in C/CPP, but I had programmed this piece of code:

```
struct vector{
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
  };

void d_print(vector *v){
    Serial.print("(");
    Serial.print(v->x);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(v->y);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(v->z);
    Serial.println(");");
    }

void newVector(vector *vec, double x, double y, double z){
  vector a;
  a.x = x;
  a.y = y;
  a.z = z;
  vec = &a;
  d_print(vec);
  }
```

When I called these methods (yes this is on an arduino, so there is a `void setup()` not an `int main()`, it worked didnt work as expected :

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vector* eye, *center, *up;
  newVector(eye, 2.3, 4.1, 5.9);
  newVector(center, 0.0,0.0,-1.0);
  newVector(up, 0.0,1.0,0.0);
  d_print(eye);
  d_print(center);
  d_print(up);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
12:22:42.198 -> (2.30, 4.10, 5.90);
12:22:42.232 -> (0.00, 0.00, -1.00);
12:22:42.232 -> (0.00, 1.00, 0.00);
12:22:42.267 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:22:42.300 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:22:42.300 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
```

I understand that the `double x, y, z` go out of scope, and so the struct stores 0.0 for when it exits `void newVector()`. How can I work around this?

I did try the following approach by assigning it to the struct's pointer :

```
void newVector(vector *vec, double x, double y, double z){
    vec->x = x;
    vec->y = y;
    vec->z = z;
    d_print(vec);
    }
```

I get a worse output:

```
12:32:31.164 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:32:31.201 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:32:31.201 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:32:31.236 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:32:31.273 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
12:32:31.273 -> (0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
```

I think this is more related to how to assign to a struct in C/CPP than to do with the Arduino software.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `newVector(eye, 2.3, 4.1, 5.9);` the function gets a copy of the value of `eye`, which is uninitialized. The function sets the copy to a specific value, it does not alter the value of the original.

Comment: But isn't eye a pointer of a vector. Even if it does get a copy of a pointer, wouldn't that make it alter the same memory location?

Comment: What is Serial? Where is it defined?

Comment: @machine_1 That's a standard Arduino class for serial communication. It's irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: Serial is inbuilt with the Arduino library to print to the Arduino's Serial Monitor, which basically communicates with the Board over a Serial port.

Comment: @Ananay Gupta, You might want to check out double pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with all variants is that you pass *uninitialized* pointers to `newVector`.

All pointer must point somewhere valid, otherwise you will have *undefined behavior* when you try to dereference the pointer (i.e. with `vec->x`).

The simple solution is to not use pointers in the `setup` function, and instead use plain structure object and then use the address-of operator `&` to pass pointers to these structure objects:

```
vector eye;
newVector(&eye, 2.3, 4.1, 5.9);
d_print(&eye);
```

Also note that the first version of the `newVector` function that you show won't work at all. Use the second variant:

```
void newVector(vector *vec, double x, double y, double z){
    vec->x = x;
    vec->y = y;
    vec->z = z;
    d_print(vec);
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay, so just to clarify, I have to initialize it with malloc?

Comment: @AnanayGupta Well you *can* use it (or `new` since the standard Arduino IDE is using C++), but I don't see any need for it. Just pass using the address-of operator as shown in my answer.

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 2 minutes, Its not letting me do this now